# Infragistics:WebCurrencyEditor allow negative values to insert

Tags: set, currency, infragistics

In Infragistics:WebCurrencyEditor controller, cannot insert negative values. I have tried with

System.Globalization.CultureInfo ci =         System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US");

ci.NumberFormat.CurrencyNegativePattern = 1;  // "-$n";

NumBox1.Culture = ci;

but this is not working for me.
How to do this?

Comment: use NumBox1.MinValue=-999999999;
I have solved the problem.

Comment: Please post your comment as an answer and, at due time, accept it. http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use NumBox1.MinValue=-999999999; I have solved the problem.